# PHP htmlentities output not correct

Tags: php, html-entities

I am trying to build a website that lists poi locations.

I have been using the google PHP MySQL store locator tutorial but still have a few issues.

The first problem is converting the string from the MYSQL database to a format that is compatible with XML

e.g.

I have a record where the name of the POI is 'Sérvier' with accent on the é

I use this to extract the name:

```
$newnode->setAttribute("name", htmlentities($row['Name'], ENT_SUBSTITUTE, "ISO-8859-15"));
```

But it outputs:

```
S& amp;eacute;vrier
```

(I have had to add spaces between the & and amp to show what I mean but I was expecting

```
"S& eacute;vrier"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you could be encoding twice, somewhere.

Comment: Are you using `DOMDocument`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so...// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is as @MichaelRushton suggested something to do with using DOMDocument

If I simply output the results into an html table format, I get the expected results

```
// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
echo "<table>";
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>";
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("id", $row['ID']);
echo "<td>". $row['ID']."</td>";
$newnode->setAttribute("name", htmlentities($row['Name'], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-15"));
echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
$newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['Type']);
echo "<td>".$row['Type']."</td>";
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['Latitude']);
echo "<td>".$row['Latitude']."</td>";
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['Longitude']);
echo "<td>".$row['Longitude']."</td>";
$newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
echo "<td>".$row['distance']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Reading the tutorial again it does suggest

> Note:  If your database contains international characters or you otherwise need to force UTF-8 output, you can use utf8_encode on the outputted data

But I have no idea how to force UTF-8 output for the XML